# Split JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on a D3 DPS calculator and i'm having a problem with a JSON-Object.
I get a JSON-Object like this:

```
{"Sockets":{"min":1,"max":1},
"Dexterity_Item":{"min":165,"max":165},
"Durability_Cur":{"min":581,"max":581},
"Durability_Max":{"min":715,"max":715},
"Attacks_Per_Second_Item_Percent":{"min":0.1,"max":0.1},
"Damage_Weapon_Delta#Arcane":{"min":315,"max":315},
"Damage_Weapon_Min#Arcane":{"min":274,"max":274},
"Damage_Weapon_Delta#Physical":{"min":161,"max":161},
"Damage_Weapon_Min#Physical":{"min":190,"max":190},
"Attacks_Per_Second_Item":{"min":1.2000000476837158,"max":1.2000000476837158},
"Steal_Health_Percent":{"min":0.03,"max":0.03}}
```

How can i split all of this values? I cant do it by name, because its "random". I would like to have a List with the stat and the value.

Comment: Learn about JSON parsing..

Comment: learn this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help is to view your JSON in an online [JSON viewer like this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).  You can hit format, and get something out of it that looks like this:

```
{
  "Sockets": {
    "min": 1,
    "max": 1
  },
  "Dexterity_Item": {
    "min": 165,
    "max": 165
  },
  "Durability_Cur": {
    "min": 581,
    "max": 581
  },
  "Durability_Max": {
    "min": 715,
    "max": 715
  },
  "Attacks_Per_Second_Item_Percent": {
    "min": 0.1,
    "max": 0.1
  },
  "Damage_Weapon_Delta#Arcane": {
    "min": 315,
    "max": 315
  },
  "Damage_Weapon_Min#Arcane": {
    "min": 274,
    "max": 274
  },
  "Damage_Weapon_Delta#Physical": {
    "min": 161,
    "max": 161
  },
  "Damage_Weapon_Min#Physical": {
    "min": 190,
    "max": 190
  },
  "Attacks_Per_Second_Item": {
    "min": 1.2000000476837158,
    "max": 1.2000000476837158
  },
  "Steal_Health_Percent": {
    "min": 0.03,
    "max": 0.03
  }
}
```

Also I really like [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/793607) for Android JSON parsing

Answer (score 0):

If you develop on android platform, you can easily use the **json api**:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

You have just to instanciate a JSONObject:

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myStringData)`

and get your data with each key from your `json String (min, max,...)`

like this:

```
int min = jsonObject.getInt("min");
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just an exemple for using JSON api

**JSON File**:

```
{
    "chapitres":{

        "chapitre":[
            {   
                "id": "1",
                "name": "La plateforme Android 1",
                "desc": "Description chapitre 1"
            },

            {   
                "id": "2",
                "name": "La plateforme Android 2",
                "desc": "Description chapitre 2"
            },

            {   
                "id": "3",
                "name": "La plateforme Android 3",
                "desc": "Description chapitre 3"
            },
            {   
                "id": "4",
                "name": "La plateforme Android 4",
                "desc": "Description chapitre 4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**JAVA CODE**:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

JSONObject chapitresJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("chapitres");

JSONArray chapitreJsonArray = chapitresJsonObject.getJSONArray("chapitre");

    for (int i = 0; i < chapitreJsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject ChapJsonObject = chapitreJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = ChapJsonObject.getString("id");
        String name = ChapJsonObject.getString("name");
        String desc = ChapJsonObject.getString("desc");
         }
```

that's all

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the names of your stats, you can get them with `JSONObject.names()`.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(...);

JSONArray stats = json.names();
for (int i = 0; i < stats.length(); i++) {
    String name = stats.getString(i);
    JSONObject stat = json.getJSONObject(name);

    stat.getInt("min");
    stat.getInt("max");
}
```